# how to track time remaining to retry fingerprint login in android?

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

I am using FingerPrint Manager for fingerprint login in my app. I found that after successive 5 failed attempts, the sensor gets disable for the 30 sec. Is there any way I can track time remains to restart sensor, so that even if the current app is closed and re-launched the remaining time to retry gets updated?

Comment: Note that the Android Compatibility Definition Documents states that the lockout time should be _at least_ 30 seconds, so I don't think you can rely on it being _exactly_ 30 seconds. As for measuring the time passed, I suppose you could persist a timestamp somewhere in the filesystem or the shared preferences. Note that placing the app in the background doesn't necessarily destroy it - it just goes in to a non-active state until it is resumed.

Comment: Hi, @Michael Thanks. I used CountDownTimer to update UI and shared preferences to remember time stamp. Also, I set a timer to 31 sec.